# migrating build flow using flow DSL into pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project that I need to migrate from the old build flow using flow dsl plugin scripts written in groovy into pipeline and I am running into several issues. Based on my code snippet below one issue I get is "expected to call Script1.func1 but wound up catching build" but it will actually trigger the build but does not seem to execute the line below "gv.funct1 (param1, param2) and the script will end with "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5". I think they are related to CPS due to the "build job" in the "func1"?  I tried putting @NonCPS before the "def func1" but it didn't work.  Any suggestions on how to get around this?

**I have a method in the script.groovy as follows:**

```
def func1 (param1, param2) {
    build job: param1, parameters: [string(name: 'PARAMETER2', value: 'param2')]
}
```

**in Pipeline I have:**

```
pipeline {
    stages {
       stage ("Build") {
           steps {
                 ...
                 gv = load "scripts.groovy"
                 
                 def myFile = readFile (fileToBeRead)

                 for (int i = 0; i < myFile.size(); i++) {
                     String[] param = ""
                     param = myFile.split(',')
                     gv.func1 (param[0], param[1])
                     ....
                 }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have `return this` at the end of `script.groovy`

Comment: At which line you have java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?